# Python Dataframe conditionally add value to existing column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm having trouble to make my basic trading bot.
I've managed to create the column buy/sell for the rows to buy or sell (https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7vg4.jpg)
to select the rows I use:

```
  df.loc[df['Buy/Sell'] == 'Buy']
```

But now for these rows I want to add the `df['Open']` value to the `df['portfolio']`

I tried the following:

```
 df.loc[(df['Buy/Sell'] == 'Sell'),'Portfolio'] = df['Portfolio'] + df['Open']
```

It turned out it didn't select anything and just did this to all rows
I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance

Comment: Please [do not post images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of your data or errors. You can include [code that creates a dataframe such as `df.to_dict()` or the output of `print(df)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) (include at least the few rows and columns that allow to reproduce your issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you require:

```
df.loc[df['Buy/Sell'] == 'Sell', 'Portfolio'] = df['Portfolio'].add(df['Open'])
```

Please consider rewriting your code to the above.